# How to ban URL showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

What we want in our system is to ban certain URL.

In our page, we have an external opinion system. What happens is that when we enter a xxxx.html page, later on, it adds to the URL a #/submit, like xxxx.html#/submit

What we want in our system is to control the URL flow. When a xxx.html page is visited, it should be added a #/dashboard like xxx.html#/dashboard and ban the autoredirection to xxx.html#/submit. And if a page like xxx.html#/submit is visited, we don't need to change the URL.

Is there some way to ban the autoredirection in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

you can use htaccess redirect rather than using javascript redirection !!!

I think this would be helpful : https://mediatemple.net/community/products/grid/204643080/how-do-i-redirect-my-site-using-a-htaccess-file

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the below which utilises the global `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and querys the HTTP Header (the url the client has taken). You can then use a switch and set cases to redirect if case condition has been met. In the instance below I've used a redirect if the HTTP_HOST was TRUE to show as an example. You could also set the cases as variables making the case URLS dynamic.

```
<?php

$address = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

if (isset($address))

    switch ($address) {

    case 'localhost:8888':

            header( 'Location: https://foo.com/test' ) ;
        break;

    case 'www.test.com/test2':

        header( 'Location: https://foo.com/test2' ) ;
        break;

    case 'www.test.com/test3':

        header( 'Location: https://foo.com/test2' ) ;
        break;

    default:

       header( 'Location: https://foo.com/' ) ;


    }

?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php